# How to store arrayList into an array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

How to store arrayList into an array in java?

Comment: Please describe in more detail what you want to achieve.

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray()

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That depends on what you want:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
// add items to the list
```

Now if you want to store the list in an array, you can do one of these:

```
Object[] arrOfObjects = new Object[]{list};
List<?>[] arrOfLists = new List<?>[]{list};
```

But if you want the list *items* in an array, do one of these:

```
Object[] arrayOfObjects = list.toArray();
String[] arrayOfStrings = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

**Reference:**

- [`Collection.toArray()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28%29)
- [`Collection.toArray(T[])`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29)

Comment: Better define the `arrOfLists` as `List<String>[]`, or maybe `List<?>[]`.

Comment: @Paŭlo I know, but `List<String>[]` is a syntax error and `List<?>` is not a huge gain :-)

Comment: Ah, right, I forgot the stupid non-generic arrays ... At least, `List<?>[]` gives no warnings for using the raw type.

Comment: @Paŭlo ok, added that change, but if you are crazy enough to store a list in an array you probably don't care about compiler warnings either :-)

Answer (score 3):

If Type is known (aka not a generics parameter) and you want an Array of Type:

```
ArrayList<Type> list = ...;
Type[] arr = list.toArray(new Type[list.size()]);
```

Otherwise

```
Object[] arr = list.toArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

You mean you want to convert an `ArrayList` to an array?

```
Object[] array = new Object[list.size()];
array = list.toArray(array);
```

Choose the appropriate class.

Answer (score 0):

```
List list = getList();
Object[] array = new Object[list.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
{
  array[i] = list.get(i);
}
```

Or just use [List#toArray()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Foo> fooList = new ArrayList<Foo>();
Foo[] fooArray = fooList.toArray(new Foo[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List list = new ArrayList();

list.add("Blobbo");

list.add("Cracked");

list.add("Dumbo");

// Convert a collection to Object[], which can store objects    

Object[] ol = list.toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the generic method [`List.toArray()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5b%5d%29):

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Foo", "Bar", "Gah");
String array[] = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
// array = ["Foo", "Bar", "Gah"]
```

Comment: The last line won't compile in Java (while it would be perfectly legal in Groovy). Javac says: `Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Expression`

Comment: @Sean: right, I just threw that in there for demonstration, I'll update the answer to make it clear...