# How to initialize the elements of an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

How do I initialize the values of an **ArrayList**?

I found this on the internet, but it doesn't work.

```
ArrayList<Kaart>[] hand = (ArrayList<Kaart>[]) new ArrayList[AANTALSPELERS];
```

All elements of `hand` are `null`. I get a `nullPointerException` because of that. Kaart is a class I created. **AANTALSPELERS** is a private static final int.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244268/how-to-store-arraylist-into-an-array-in-java

Comment: Arrays of references get initialized to `null` everywhere... So you'll have to assign `new ArrayList<Kaart>()` to the array "cells" before you use these.

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358546/casting-between-arraylists-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the correct way, using generics. Notice that the warning is unavoidable (you can use a  `@SuppressWarnings` annotation if that's a problem):

```
ArrayList<Kaart>[] array = (ArrayList<Kaart>[]) new ArrayList[AANTALSPELERS];
for (int i = 0; i < AANTALSPELERS; i++)
    array[i] = new ArrayList<Kaart>();
```

Answer (score 6):

An array of `Object`s has elements initialized to `null` (just like how an array of `int`s is initialized to zeros).

So before you can use the elements of the array, you have to initialize each element.

```
ArrayList[] al = new ArrayList[5];

for( int i = 0; i < al.length; i++ )
    al[i] = new ArrayList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Guava's [ListMultimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html) where the key is the index.

```
ListMultimap<Integer, Kaart>
```

It will take care of all the list initialization for you.

Answer (score 0):

you created a `Array` of `AANTALSPELERS` elements and each element can hold an `ArrayList`.

Since you have not added any `ArrayList` to the `Array`, the `Array` will have the default element `null`.

You also need to do something like this to populate the `Array` with `ArrayList`

```
for(int i = 0; i < hand.length; i++)
    hand[i] = new ArrayList();// or the arraylist you have
```