# How to convert an ArrayList to an Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to store arrayList into an array in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244268/how-to-store-arraylist-into-an-array-in-java)

I want to know how can I convert an ArrayList into an Array.

Is there any method to do so in Java?

Can anyone help me about this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

yep, there is check out the List API:

[**List.toArray(T[])**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29)

**Example:**

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
list.add(3);
Integer[] arr = list.toArray(new Integer[list.size()]);
```

Comment: I need to get results from a ResultSet in an Array after converting the ArrayList to Array.  How to do so?

Comment: iterate over your result set, populate the arraylist and then convert it into the array appriately as shown in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is the .toArray() function for an array list that should accomplish that.